# Prove that the Laplace trasform is a Linear trasformation

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, integration, laplace-transform

Could you help me prove that the Laplace Trasform is a Linear trasformation?

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Where do you struggle, what have you tried?

Comment: Isn't this a pretty standard question. I mean a simple search or any textbook would give the answer. And of course as @DanZimm says, what did you do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$
\int_X \alpha f + \beta g \, \mathrm{d} \mu = \alpha \int_X f \, \mathrm{d} \mu + \beta \int_X g \, \mathrm{d} \mu
$$

Answer (score 4):

Integral is a linear function ;)